# How can I replace fonts in XeTeX?

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm using XeTeX because I want to use some fonts from my system. The next should work (I think).

I have this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,spanish]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}

\font\reenie="ReenieBeanie"
\font\cuprum="Cuprum"

\renewcommand{\sffamily}{\reenie}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\cuprum}

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

The compilation fails, although I get the document with the new font and some weird symbols arround it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compilation fails"?  And what weird symbols do you get?

Comment: This is an unrelated point, but you should probably use polyglossia rather than babel for XeLaTeX.

Comment: In addition to Jan answer below, I strongly encourage you to read fontspec manual if you want to play with fonts in XeTeX/LuaTeX.

Comment: When I asked this question, It was my first time playing with XeTeX. After Jan's answer I read the fontspec manual. It's a great package (and I think should be part of XeTeX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If nothing else, the use of `\renewcommand*` is pretty suspect.  I always use the `fontspec` package to select font.  See if this works:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,spanish]{article}
 \usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{babel}
 \usepackage{fontspec}

 \setsansfont{DroidSans}
 \setmonofont{DroidSansMono}


 \begin{document} 
 \ldots
 \end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It compiles but the text is missing. Is `fontspec` XeTeX specific?

Comment: What system do you use?  Which version of XeTeX/fontspec?  Are there any messages you get from XeTeX during compilation that could be relevant to this problem?

Comment: Yes, fontspec is XeLaTeX specific. Do make sure too that you pick fonts you actually have installed!

Comment: My fault. I was defining `\font` first when I should haven't. It does work now.

Comment: @Tomas: Remember to actually try the example you post :-)